# Https requst to external resourse get stuck randomly and no response for 3 minutes

Tags: java, ssl, jboss, jax-rs, httpclient

I am using java 8 and Jboss EAP 7.3.9. When I call 3-d party service randomly my application sometimes didn't get response. It's repro only on specific env(It's located in China region). On other env with same code it's not repro. In logs I see next warning:

```
13:30:05,000 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff0a9c8950:73df8c47:646382ee:1257 in state  RUN
13:30:05,003 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffff0a9c8950:73df8c47:646382ee:1257 invoked while multiple threads active within it.
13:30:05,006 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012381: Action id 0:ffff0a9c8950:73df8c47:646382ee:1257 completed with multiple threads - thread default task-2 was in progress with java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:464)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:165)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:109)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1305)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
    org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
    org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
    org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:320)
    org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:447)
    org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:64)
    org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.get(ClientInvocationBuilder.java:191)
    com.my.service.impl.ClientServiceImpl.validate(ClientServiceImpl.java:99)
```

I use next code to execute request :

```
Client restClient = ClientBuilder.newBuilder();
WebTarget target = restClient.target(uri);
               response = target.queryParam("token", value).queryParam("key", Key).request().get().readEntity(Response.class);
```

What is the possible reasons why it randomly fails? Tried to reproduce with the curl command but without success.

Comment: That is an *incomplete* stacktrace.  You have omitted the part of the log message that shows the exception message.   And if you are getting an exception, that is not an indication that it is "stuck".  Rather, it most likely means that it failed.

Comment: updated stack trace. The request stuck for approximately one minute and then I see this log. But the successful response I got for approximately 2 seconds.

Comment: Possible reasons for "random" failure could be: 1) random network failures, 2) problems caused by network, router, firewall, etc misconfiguration, 3) network congestion, 4) some kind of anti-DOS or anti-scraper defenses being triggered, 5) bugs on the server side, 6) etcetera.

Comment: Ah ... based on your updated log message, another possibility strikes me.  It could be that the server is draining its source of entropy (for generating random keys) and that is blocking it.   But that presupposes that that the server has been set up the wrong way; see https://serverfault.com/questions/1012010/can-ssl-tls-deplete-the-entropy-pool-of-my-server

Comment: My advice would be to look on the server side to see if problems show up there; e.g. in the logs.  If that doesn't help, use your favorite packet sniffing tool to try to isolate the problem to the client, server or network.

Comment: @StephenC same code is working well on another env. It's some infra issue I guess. The server is located in the China region. But why it's not repro with curl command then.

Comment: Probably because what you are sending with curl is (maybe subtly) different.  Packet sniffing may show what the differences are.